# I am currently working on Javascript and stuck with using for loop in objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

```
[ { name: 'rajesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020' },
  { name: 'ramesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020' },
  { name: 'abhi', type: 'int', value: '5' }
 ]
```

1. I need to use for loop
2. I need output like this('rajesh':'07/21/2020,'ramesh':'07/21/2020','abhi': 5
3. Need to use JSON.stringify

Comment: Please add the details on what you have done so far here.

Comment: Your output is enclosed in parentheses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
let arr = [ { name: 'rajesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020' },
  { name: 'ramesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020' },
  { name: 'abhi', type: 'int', value: '5' }
 ];


 let result = {};

 for(i= 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
 }

 console.log(result);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Thank u sonEtLumiere

Answer (score 2):

something like this maybe,

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'rajesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020'
  },
  {
    name: 'ramesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020'
  },
  {
    name: 'abhi',
    type: 'int',
    value: '5'
  }
]

const convertedData = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({
  name,
  value
}) => [name, value]))

console.log(convertedData)
console.log(JSON.stringify(convertedData))
```

Steps Taken:

- Convert `data`  to touple (for getting it converted using `Object.fromEntries`)
- Create Object from the touples
- Convert to JSON

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: 'rajesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020'
  },
  {
    name: 'ramesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020'
  },
  {
    name: 'abhi',
    type: 'int',
    value: '5'
  }
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.name] = curr.value
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result, JSON.stringify(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [ { name: 'rajesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020' },
  { name: 'ramesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020' },
  { name: 'abhi', type: 'int', value: '5' }
 ];


 let result = {};

 for(i= 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    result[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
 }

 console.log(result);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'rajesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020'
  },
  {
    name: 'ramesh',
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    value: '07/21/2020'
  },
  {
    name: 'abhi',
    type: 'int',
    value: '5'
  }
]

const convertedData = Object.fromEntries(data.map(({
  name,
  value
}) => [name, value]))

console.log(convertedData)
console.log(JSON.stringify(convertedData))
```